# Is a single hadoop Mapper object used for more than one call to map()?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

So, I have a Mapper that updates an HBase table.  In the map() function, I :

1) instantiate an HBaseConfiguration

2) instantiate an HTable

3) call hTable.put() a bunch of times to add rows

4) call hTable.flushCommits() to flush my changes

5) call HConnectionManager.deleteConnection() to kill the connection to HBase

However, this seems inefficient.  I would like to instantiate the HBaseConfiguration and the HTable in the constructor for my Mapper class.  Then I could have my mapper class implement Closeable, calling hTable.flushCommits() and HConnectionManager.deleteConnection() in the close() method.  That way, in each call to map(), I'd be buffering my put() calls, and would be flushing all the changes at once, when close() is called.

However, this is only worthwhile if the Mapper object is re-used for multiple calls to map().  Otherwise, I may as well leave my code alone.

So the main question is : are Mapper objects used for more than one call to map()?

The bonus question is : would the re-written code be more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `setup` and `cleanup`. `setup` runs once before `map` is called a bunch of times, and `cleanup` is called once after all the `maps` are called. You override these just like you override `map`.

Use private member objects for your `HBaseConfiguration` and `HTable`. Initialize them in the `setup`. Do your `hTable.put()` in your `map`. Do `hTable.flushCommits()` and `HConnectionManager.deleteConnection()` in your `cleanup`. The only thing you might want to be careful is to flush the commits more than just at the end in the case you are buffering more data than your memory can handle. In which case, you might want to flush every 1000 records or something in the map by keeping track of number of records you've seen.

This will definitely be more efficient! Opening and closing that connection is going to incur a significant amount of overhead.

Check out the [documentation for Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context%29)

Comment: Hi,
I would like to add that sentence about HTable flushing ("The only thing you might want to be careful is to flush the commits more than just at the end in the case you are buffering more data than your memory can handle") is not completely true. HTable has underling buffer when it is filled it is flushed automatically. Please read documentation about setWriteBufferSize(long writeBufferSize) method.
http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html